# **STM32f427 UART with DMA** The highest bit sometimes is 1 when receive data from console

Tags: uart, dma, stm32f4

I got a problem when using STM32f427 UART with DMA(using stm cube HAL library).

I would like make a console echo function, so I reply received data immediately in uart idle interrupt handler function.

But sometimes, the highest bit of received data will be 1, when I input any key in keyboard.
such as following

```
0x31 -> 0xB1
0x32 -> 0xB2
0x40 -> 0xC0
```

Does someone have any idea? the code segment as following.

Thank you very much.

**My uart configuration as following**

```
uart_handler.Instance          = USARTx;
uart_handler.Init.BaudRate     = baudrate;
uart_handler.Init.WordLength   = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
uart_handler.Init.StopBits     = UART_STOPBITS_1;
uart_handler.Init.Parity       = UART_PARITY_NONE;
uart_handler.Init.HwFlowCtl    = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
uart_handler.Init.Mode         = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
uart_handler.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_8;
```

**My PIN and DMA channels configuration as following**

```
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin       = USARTx_TX_PIN;
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode      = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull      = GPIO_PULLUP;
GPIO_InitStruct.Speed     = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = USARTx_TX_AF;
HAL_GPIO_Init(USARTx_TX_GPIO_PORT, &GPIO_InitStruct);
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = USARTx_RX_PIN;
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode      = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull      = GPIO_NOPULL;
GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = USARTx_RX_AF;
HAL_GPIO_Init(USARTx_RX_GPIO_PORT, &GPIO_InitStruct);
hdma_tx.Instance                 = USARTx_TX_DMA_STREAM;
hdma_tx.Init.Channel             = USARTx_TX_DMA_CHANNEL;
hdma_tx.Init.Direction           = DMA_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH;
hdma_tx.Init.PeriphInc           = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
hdma_tx.Init.MemInc              = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
hdma_tx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
hdma_tx.Init.MemDataAlignment    = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
hdma_tx.Init.Mode                = DMA_NORMAL;
hdma_tx.Init.Priority            = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
hdma_tx.Init.FIFOMode            = DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;
hdma_tx.Init.FIFOThreshold       = DMA_FIFO_THRESHOLD_FULL;
hdma_tx.Init.MemBurst            = DMA_MBURST_INC16;
hdma_tx.Init.PeriphBurst         = DMA_MBURST_INC16;
HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_tx);
```

/* Associate the initialized DMA handle to the UART handle */

```
__HAL_LINKDMA(huart, hdmatx, hdma_tx);
```

/* Configure the DMA handler for reception process */

```
hdma_rx.Instance                 = USARTx_RX_DMA_STREAM;
hdma_rx.Init.Channel             = USARTx_RX_DMA_CHANNEL;
hdma_rx.Init.Direction           = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
hdma_rx.Init.PeriphInc           = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
hdma_rx.Init.MemInc              = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
hdma_rx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
hdma_rx.Init.MemDataAlignment    = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
hdma_rx.Init.Mode                = DMA_NORMAL;
hdma_rx.Init.Priority            = DMA_PRIORITY_HIGH;
hdma_rx.Init.FIFOMode            = DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;
hdma_rx.Init.FIFOThreshold       = DMA_FIFO_THRESHOLD_FULL;
hdma_rx.Init.MemBurst            = DMA_MBURST_INC16;
hdma_rx.Init.PeriphBurst         = DMA_MBURST_INC16;
```

And use uart idle interrupt to receive data.

```
uint32_t temp;
if((__HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(huart, UART_FLAG_IDLE) != RESET))
{
__HAL_UART_CLEAR_IDLEFLAG(huart);
HAL_UART_DMAStop(&uart_handler);
temp = uart_handler.hdmarx->Instance->NDTR;
g_usart_info.rx_len =  USART_DMA_RECV_LEN - temp;
g_usart_info.receive_flag = 1;
g_usart_info.usart_dma_tx_buff = g_usart_info.usart_dma_rx_buff[0] ;
memset(g_usart_info.usart_dma_rx_buff, 0,                
sizeof(g_usart_info.usart_dma_rx_buff));
__HAL_UART_CLEAR_FLAG(&uart_handler, UART_FLAG_RXNE);
g_usart_info.usart_dma_rx_buff[0] = 0;
HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&uart_handler, g_usart_info.usart_dma_rx_buff, 
USART_DMA_RECV_LEN);
}
```

Thank you.

I traced the function of UART_Receive_IT and added debug code.
and insert break point for int a = *(huart->pRxBuffPtr - 1);

I found huart->Instance->DR is 0x31 but int a is 0xB1.

I tried to disable other interrupt but it still cannot be solved.

```
if(huart->Init.Parity == UART_PARITY_NONE)
      {
        *huart->pRxBuffPtr++ = (uint8_t)(huart->Instance->DR & (uint8_t)0x00FF);
                if(*(huart->pRxBuffPtr - 1) != 0x31)
                {
                    int a = *(huart->pRxBuffPtr - 1);
                    a = a;
                }
      }
      else
      {
        *huart->pRxBuffPtr++ = (uint8_t)(huart->Instance->DR & (uint8_t)0x007F);
      }
```

========================================================================

**I found the problem point**

```
RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = (RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1 /*| RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2*/);
```

If I comment `RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2`, this problem could be solved.
But I don't know why, it is official sample code. I think it should be right.

Comment: You could make sure that your computer's UART is set up correctly (start bit, stop bit, parity). I can't imagine that the problem could be the clocks, but you could seeing if all the clocks are set up correctly. If that still doesn't work, then I would use STM32CubeMX to generate the code again, and see how it differs with what you have.

Comment: Hi thank for your response , about UART configure , I think it is correct, because it work well if set to 9600, but it has problem when set to 115200.
under baudrate 115200 the incorrect output as below.
I press down "1" on keyboard and send to my board by uart
"111±11111111111111111111111111111111111111±11"

most of output is correct, but sometime it will be ±

And my development target is not official develop board, it maybe is a hardware design issue on my side only, I am checking it.

But in actually, if I comment RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2 in my code, uart is work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the root cause for this question.
I use official sample code for my board but those sample code is for official development board the board is with embedded stlink/v2 circuit and it will pass 8M hz to the STM32F4 chip for HSE clock.

But my board does not have the circuit , so I have to use external stlink/v2 module to develop my board.

So, I need to do below change.

WAS:
RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_BYPASS;

IS:
RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_LSE_ON;

After change, my problem is be solved.

And thanks Hein Wessels for watching and help :).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, then it does sound like a clock issue.

- Do you have an oscilloscope? Instead of doing an echo test you could just send a known byte from the STM32. I usually send `0xAA` or `0x55`. Then you can measure the timing of your STM32's UART and verify if it is correct.
- Sometimes at higher clock speeds the accuracy of the peripheral's clock will decrease. You could also try to increase the speed of your system clock.

**Thought:** Looking at your code again I think I might have found the problem. In your UART config change

```
uart_handler.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_8;
```

to

```
uart_handler.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
```

This will force the STM32 to look more finely at the incoming bytes and *could* resolve your problem. In my understanding `16x` oversampling is the typical configuration used, even at lower UART speeds.

Comment: Thank for reply, for your suggestion, I will measure it later :),

And about OverSampling ,
I known the original setting is UART_OVERSAMPLING_16, but uart cannot work if I use the value , but it could work when set to UART_OVERSAMPLING_8.

But, uart is not working under UART_OVERSAMPLING_16 problem also be solved if  RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2 is be commented.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What happens? My guess that the clock driving your UART is not fast enough then. Try to max out your system clock **AND** the clock going to your UART.